# How to Add Multiple GPS location's Proximity Alerts in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-intent, proximity

i m developing a GPS based application . i have a location list , i want that to put all into Proximity Alerts so they fire when i reach near by any place. how to implement and add multiple Alerts into my Project. 
regards, a.Q.Ghouri

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem on doing that. If you read the docs for [`LocationManager.addProximityAlert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), you'll see that this manager maps areas to intents. When an area is reached, the intent you registered is fired. So just register a proximity alert with a different intent for each location.